# Why does this viewcontroller require an intitializer?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
```

I get an error below saying class 'playMusicViewController' has no intitializers, I am unsure as to why I would need an initializer in a view controller class as my other view controller has no view initializers

```
class playMusicViewController: UIViewController {

    var play : MPMusicPlayerController

    var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollection

    @IBAction func play (sender: AnyObject){

        func playMusic() -> MPMusicPlayerController {

            var musicPlayer: MPMusicPlayerController = MPMusicPlayerController()

            return musicPlayer
        }

        playMusic()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {   
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func prepareToPlay() -> Bool{

            let myplayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()

            myplayer.setQueueWithItemCollection(selectedSong)

            play = myplayer

            myplayer.play()

            return true
        }}


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every var should be initialised in Swift, otherwise it will complain.
You can make the variables optional if you don't want to initialise them, and `nil` will be assigned to them initially.

```
var play : MPMusicPlayerController?
var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollection?
```

From [Swift's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

> Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the property’s definition

Answer (score 0):

In swift all variables have to be initialize before super.init unless declared optional, in your case you have two variables that need to be initialized

```
var play : MPMusicPlayerController 
var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollection
```

You can avoid have to create a initializer by declaring the variable optional

```
var play : MPMusicPlayerController?
var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollection?
```

or you can avoid have to create a initializer by initializing the variable before hand (in case you don't need to pass any values to it

```
var play = MPMusicPlayerController()
var selectedSong = MPMediaItemCollection()
```

In case you need to pass values you can use lazy initializer as well

You can find more about lazy initialization [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

In swift we have to initialise var in following manner -

**Optional property**

**Lazy property**

**Property have default value**

In your case you don`t initialise your var

```
var play : MPMusicPlayerController 
var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollectio
```

you can initialise them like following -

```
var play : MPMusicPlayerController?
var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollection?

var play = MPMusicPlayerController()
var selectedSong = MPMediaItemCollection()
```

hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Classes and structures must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.

In your case `play` and `selectedSong` are stored properties.

```
//Snippet from your code
var play : MPMusicPlayerController
var selectedSong : MPMediaItemCollection
```

In order to initialise `play` and `selectedSong` the compiler throws an error so that it has an appropriate place to initialise properties before your class is used. That is why you need an initialiser.

**Note:** Adding an initialiser is one way to assign initial values to properties. See [Initialisers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) for more ways.